# How to display folder contents overview and folder statistics?

Tags: linux, windows

Is there a graphical tool for Windows or Linux to show and plot detailed folder statistics?
For instance how much `%` of the space is allocated to images, multimedia, text,...?

Free software is preferred, but commercial solutions are also sought out. Command line tools or scripts are welcome too.

Update (Dec '12): [Salamander Commander](http://www.altap.cz/salamander/screenshots/) offers such functionality on Windows through "DiskMap":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the best tool for that:

http://windirstat.info/

> On start up, it reads the whole directory tree once and then presents
>   it in three useful views:
>
> - The directory list, which resembles the tree view of the Windows
>     Explorer but is sorted by file/subtree size,
> - The treemap, which shows
>     the whole contents of the directory tree straight away,
> - The extension
>     list, which serves as a legend and shows statistics about the file
>     types.

On the right hand side shows how much space is taken up by file types:

[image]

Comment: good pointer. Fast software. I am missing a reporting feature though. It would be great if one could select and group some of the results. (PS: I included linux software as criteria as well, and apologize for that)... meanwhile I am using windirstat.